# How to modifiy path for JDK for NeurophStudio

Tags: neuroph

I tried do install NeurophStudio on Win 10, but when i try to run it i got this message
[image]

I installed this program on my hard drive, but my windows is installed on my SSD.

How can i change --jdkhome destination on NeurophStudio, because i didnt install any NetBeans? 
What do i need to run to enter that --jdkhome instrunction, and how to I enter my path like C:\bla\bla\jdk12 or C:/bla/bla/jdk12

UPDATE:
I tried installing it on my SSD, but same result as before.
When i run javac --version in cmd, i get this:

[image]

I have java jkd path in JAVA_HOME aswell:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In windows try this: (Works for some people)

First install latest version

> https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Find the instalation Neuroph Studio folder and when look for a `neurophstudio\etc\neurophstudio.conf` file.

Open it with e.g notepad++ and search this property`#jdkhome="/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20"`

Update it for your actual path like this `jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"` and remove `#`.
Save and exit.

If this solution remove initial error messege box, but program after launch quit immediately probably you didn't update your JDK (latest version).

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't find the JDK, but it's actually looking for the JRE. Install [that](https://www.java.com/en/download/), and you should be good.